# Core Graphics Error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I'm getting the following error when I call DrawRect in my custom UIView subclass:

```
CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
```

My DrawRect method in my UIView subclass 'EVGameView' is implemented as follows:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 100);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);
}
```

and I instantiate my EVGameView class in my viewController 'viewDidLoadMethod' with:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    srand(time(0));

    [super viewDidLoad];

    gameBoard = [[EVBoard alloc] init];
    [gameBoard initBoard:10 : 10 : mainBoard];

    gameView = [[EVGameView alloc] init];          // EVGameView instance

            .
            .
            .

}
```

An I call the drawRect method in the following method:

```
- (void)drawStartPosition
{
    CGRect rect;
    rect.origin = startPos;
    rect.size.width = 10;
    rect.size.height = 10;
    [gameView drawRect: rect];
}
```

It appears no context has been setup as UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() returns 'nil'. I've seen examples on youTube where people have an identical drawRect method and it works fine. I've set up a separate view in the .xib file and linked it to my gameView instance but still no luck.
Any help with this is much appreciated!

Thanks-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say where you call `drawStartPosition`, but that's the problem. Basically, you shouldn't call `drawRect:` yourself, instead you should call `setNeedsDisplay` and allow the system to complete all of the appropriate setup before it actually asks your view to draw itself into the supplied context.

Comment: O.K. thanks, it works! I call drawStartPosition from another method in the view controller. What if I need to pass a CGRect, will setNeedsDisplayInRect work?

Comment: `setNeedsDisplayInRect` will render only the passed rect to the screen.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, but when I initially called 'setNeedsDisplay' 'drawRect' was called every time, as I set a break point here. Now when I call the former drawRect is no longer called. The only major change I made is adding a pointer to an object containing CGRect's in my UIView subclass interface. Ever heard of anything like this? Many thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: No. Most likely you have inadvertently released the view (or your reference to it) or passed a zero or invalid frame to be drawn.

Comment: I found the problem - I was declaring an instance of my UIView subclass in viewDidLoad. When I took this out it worked. I thought to use instance methods (-), like drawRect, one had to declare an actual instance. Now with just a pointer to the view it works fine. Thanks for all your help.